# How to keep input value from a modal when navigating to other modal?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Basically I have a modal where user can Input the question (this is not yet saved to the database). If the user input question name and click create question it will navigate to the next modal to save the question.

The second modal will have the question input from the modal 1. When I click cancel from modal 2 it will get back to Modal 1 and will not erase the input question which is question name.

What I want is that when I navigate back the input will not be erase from modal 1.

How Do i keep the input from modal one even though I navigated to the other modal ? Thank you.

## User Input the question

[image: modal1]

## This is the second modal

[image: modal2]

## HTML from modal 1

```
<input matInput
              #questionSearch 
              [ngClass]="!hasSelectedQuestion() ? '' : 'hidden'"
              [matAutocomplete]="auto"
              [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
              formControlName="question"
              required
              class="full-width"
            />
```

## script when modal 2 button cancel is clicked

```
cancel(): void {
    this.data$.next(null);
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create service that can help to save temporary data.